# openpyxl convert CSV to EXCEL

Tags: python, linux, openpyxl

How can I convert a CSV file with `:` delimiter to XLS (Excel sheet) using `openpyxl` module?

Comment: nothing, I have a csv file and i just want to convert in excel. I am new in python so no clue.

Comment: On stackoverflow your questions are answered but no one will do the job for you.

Comment: @Satish I believe what dav1d is saying is that SO has this unspoken rule about giving men fish, as opposed to teaching them to fish. Anyways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802417/how-to-save-an-excel-worksheet-as-csv-from-python-unix.

Comment: @Johnthexiii Thanks! but that example is from excel to csv.. I am looking opposite solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

f = open(r'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\herp.csv')

csv.register_dialect('colons', delimiter=':')

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='colons')

wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = r"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\herp.xlsx"

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.title = "A Snazzy Title"

for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
    for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
        column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
        ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = cell

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: I got this error [spatel@mg0008 work]$ python26 c2x.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c2x.py", line 17, in <module>
    for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: Nice, but resulting file opens with all number fields reporting that they are saved as text instead of as a number...

Comment: Found the fix to the numbers as text issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971556/openpyxl-python-writing-csv-to-excel-gives-number-formatted-as-text

Comment: Using `enumerate(start=1)` is a nice way to eliminate those `+ 1`.  Also note that you can directly specify `cell(row=row_index, column=column_index)` instead of building a string.

Comment: To make this work I had to change the 3rd line to `from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter` and then change the penultimate line to `ws['%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))].value = cell`

Comment: Change the import to openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

Answer (score 67):

A much simpler, minimalist solution:

```
import csv
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: This is better answer. Appending is IMO better way than ws.cell() method.

Comment: Corrupted and break format on many csv files

Answer (score 2):

Here is Adam's solution expanded to strip out characters that openpyxl considers illegal and will throw an exception for:

```
import re
from openpyxl.cell.cell import ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE
...
##ws.append(row) - Replace with the code below
for i in row:
    ws.append([ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.sub('',i)])
```

ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE is a compiled regular expression containing the characters openpyxl deems "illegal".  The code is simply substituting those characters with an empty string.

Source: [Bitbucket openpyxl issue #873 - Remove illegal characters instead of throwing an exception](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/873/remove-illegal-characters-instead-of)

Comment: I think you may have meant:`ws.append([ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.sub('', _i) for _i in row])`

Answer (score 1):

On top of the suggestion by John, I slightly modified my script using  function to remove the apostrophe of string for all raw data. This way, I managed to check all raw data (string and number), which were also placed in respective cell. Lastly, I assign numeric data to float type starting from row 20 onward. This is because all numeric data existed from row 20th onward, while all data above were text only.

**cell_value = cell.replace('"', '')**

Below is my script:

```
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open(filepath1_csv) as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
    for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
        column_letter = column_index + 1
        cell_value = cell.replace('"', '')
        ws.cell(row = row_index + 1, column = column_letter).value = cell_value

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=20, min_col=1, max_col=5, 
max_row=ws.max_row):
for cell in row:
    if cell.value is None:
        break
    else:
        cell.value = float(cell.value)

wb.save(filename = filepath1_xlsx)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the comment in a proper formatting? Images are not the best medium to display code.

Comment: Hi Alex Metsai, I will change the format and thanks for your suggestion!