# Downloading and saving CSV file without quotes

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to use Python to download reports and save them as CSV files.  One of the problems I can't figure out is how to get the data in the CSV file to not have quotes around it.  When these files eventually get used in Excel, all the columns are formatted as text, instead of numbers.

Example row from the CSV file: 
"Branch Banking & Trust Company","Inside Sales","USD","10.00"

Here is the code I am using:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import base64
import json
import sys

sf = Salesforce(username="email"
            ,password="password"
            ,security_token="token")

#print "get sid " + str(sf.session_id)
sid = str(sf.session_id)
urlin = "https://na52.salesforce.com/" + sys.argv[1] + "?
view=d&snip&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv"

response = requests.get(urlin,
              headers = sf.headers, cookies = {'sid' : sid})

#response.contents
print response.content
```

Any help you can provide to save the CSV file without those quotes is greatly appreciated.

Below is the next step in the process, which converts the csv files to excel and saves them.

```
import csv
import sys
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

nfilename = sys.argv[1]
print(nfilename)
nfilename2 = sys.argv[2]
print(nfilename2)

f = open(nfilename, 'r')

csv.register_dialect('commas', delimiter=',')

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='commas')
#sys.argv[1]
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = nfilename2

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.title = "Sheet 1"

for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
    column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
    ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = cell

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if the company name had a `,` inside it like `"Branch Banking Company, Inc"`?

Comment: Also, how are you writing the file to CSV? Can you share that part of your code?

Comment: In what format do you recieve your data? as a String with commas, as json. Please give us this information

Comment: @pault  Good question, I would want it to stay as one string, not be split into another column.

Comment: @pault  I added the next code block I am using to save it as csv and then convert to excel

Comment: @MushroomMauLa  I am not exactly sure what you're asking.  The 5th line on this post is an example from the csv file I get.

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971556/openpyxl-python-writing-csv-to-excel-gives-number-formatted-as-text

Comment: That is very helpful, I think I'm close to making it work for me.  The only other thing I can't figure out is how to set the filename to be dynamic.  In the scripts I have above, I can define what the file name should be in a batch file that uses this script over and over.  In the scripts on the page you linked, it is hard coding a specific file name.