# Openpyxl number_format not modifying cell values derived from formula

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Openpyxl's 'number_format' is not modifying cell values derived from formulas because the resulting values are of Type String in Python.

I need the data in a particular custom format for a software that reads trajectory information.

NOTE: I already saw the same issue addressed here: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/376/number-format-not-refreshing-cells

> I agree with the original answer: the issue is that excel is not storing the data resulting from the formulas in its cache. The data is stored as a string. I am just not sure how to change the data from String to int once it is read by Openpyxl:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
wb.active
f = open(r"...\....\...\automated.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    ws.append(row)
f.close()
wb.save(r"...\...\...\...\automated.xlsx")

sheet=wb.active
wb.guess_types = True
sheet['F1'] = '***** Time Start'
rowNumber = 2  # Start reading from row 3
for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws, 3):  # 3 is the starting row to write on
    rowNumber += 1
    cellObj = ws.cell(row=i, column=6)  # 6 is the column to start writing on
    cellObj.value = '=OFFSET(B6,E{0},0)'.format(str(rowNumber).format(i))
    cellObj.number_format = 'dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss.000 "UTCG"'
    if i == 25:
        break
ws = wb.active

wb.save(r"...\...\...\...\automated.xlsx")
```

I know the code is working because the values stored as '0' are modified by the code perfectly (see highlight) because they do NOT use any formula for that cell:

[image: Excel Output]

NOTE: The number_format is applied to ALL the cells (I checked this for each row):

[image: result of number_format in output]

But since the cell is a string it does not reflect the changes.

> > I am fairly new to Python and attempted to cast `cellObj.value` as an int but that did not work.

Any help or advice on how to do this would be appreciated. I have dug through Stack Overflow for the past 4 days and have not seen any solution to this issue. Thank you!

edit: I am using the latest version of openpyxl 2.5.3 and tried this:
[openpyxl python - writing csv to excel gives 'number formatted as text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971556/openpyxl-python-writing-csv-to-excel-gives-number-formatted-as-text) but it did not work - all my values turned into Zero's:

[image: Output Result Null]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the strings to datetime objects using the `strptime` method.